# Does zina in iddah spoils iddah?

Tags: sunni, iddah

I am performing iddah after getting divorce from my husband, 
still one month is left to complete. Due to some urgent problem I needed a man's help and to solve my issue he demanded  me to do zina. I did zina with him unwillingly.

I know its a sin and I continuously ask for forgiveness, but please tell me does it make any difference to iddah? Did it spoil my iddah?

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons/wisdom behind keeping iddah is to protect the lineage and to be certain on the fatherhood in case of pregnancy.

So, *logically*, one has to wait another 3 months before she can legally be eligible for other marriage.

Answer (score 0):

Your iddah has been broken and the talaq has been revoked unless the talaq is an irivokable one then your iddah would start over just this time it would be for the person you zina with and you’ll have to explain to your husband the situation

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you’re saying unwillingly, so basically he raped you , secondly, I think you wanted it ….you probably got caught, hence you asking for forgiveness